# User associated with FileMode.Open

Tags: c#

Is there a way to find out what user is trying to do this?

```
 using (FileStream Istream = new FileStream(Server.MapPath("~/images/fool.jpg"), FileMode.Open))
 {
     ...
 }
```

I am getting a permissions error and want to which user my localhost is using to access it.

I have tried:

```
WindowsIdentity wi = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
```

Is that accurate?

Comment: I usually use Procmon: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx (filter for your process (e.g. w3wp.exe for IIS) and ACCESS_DENIED)

Answer (score 0):

As per Dunken's Comment:

I used Procmon and got the user, added the user, no dice.

Then it struck me:

Read only was selected on the file!

Eventhough, I had lots of permissions, Sourcegear was read-onlying my files!

Never had this issue with MemoryStream.